# C++: unimplemented: non-static data member initializers

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, non-static

I have the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    vector<int> vic;
    bool visitato = false;
};

int main (){
    vector<node> grafo;
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    int n, m, s, from, to;
    in >> n >> m >> s;
    grafo.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){        
        in >> from >> to;
        grafo[from].vic.push_back(to);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grafo.size(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < grafo[i].vic.size(); j++)
            cout << "From node " << i << " to node " << grafo[i].vic[j] << endl;
}
```

And (on Ubuntu) I type the following command:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -DEVAL -static -O2 -o visita visita.cpp -std=c++0x
```

And I get the following error:

```
visita.cpp:10:21: sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers
visita.cpp:10:21: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘visitato’
```

At my home it works fine but here in the university it doesn't. The command to executed has been posted by our teacher. Then why doesn't it work in the uni but it does in my home?

Comment: Different version of g++. Yours is later and supports the in-class initialisation feature of C++11, the university one does not.

Comment: It tells you what's wrong. The compiler at your university does not support C++11 non-static data member initializers. REF: visita.cpp:10:21: sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers

Comment: Adding to the comment by @AlexanderBrevig, `struct node` is not static, so the initializer `= false` of the data member `visitato` is not implemented in the GCC you're using at home. Use `gcc --version` to get the compiler version both at home and at university. Besides, use `-std=c++11`, as `-std=c++0x` is deprecated.

Comment: ok guys, my gcc version is 4.6.3 at uni. But why he told us to use that command if he knows we must work on these pcs ? ... :\ PS, I tried putting `std=c++11` but it doesnt work: `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11`

Comment: @DevSolar: It's deprecated _now_, yes, but it wasn't then...

Comment: @bogALT: Indeed, that ancient compiler won't recognise `c++11`, only the old name of `c++0x`, which is now deprecated. You should specify `c++11` on a modern compiler, and not expect complete C++11 support if that doesn't work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That was, basically, the whole idea. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non static data member initializers available since [GCC 4.7](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). So, check your GCC version.

Answer (score 2):

Solved with this code:

```
struct node{
    vector<int> vic;
    bool visitato;
    node() : visitato(false) {}    
};
```